# How to pass Id number from Angular to Spring basing on name from JSON

Tags: mysql, json, angular, spring

I have issue that really made me give up. The logic that I want to get is making order basing on recip (name and id). I'm getting JSON which looks like this:

```
[
  {
"recip_id": 1,
"quantity": 500,
"price": 8.9,
"quantity_item": 0.5,
"name": "Carrot juice 100%",
"orders": [
  {
    "orders_id": 1,
    "date": "2019-05-11T22:00:00.000+0000"
  }
 ]
}
]
```

And what I need to get is showing in Angular component name of the recip (like Carrot Juice) make from it drop down list (selectable) and basing on that name pass Id of the recip ("recip_id") back to component and put into the orders table as foreign key "recip_recip_id".

My best try (I'm not really good in Angular) is:

```html
  <br><br><br>
      <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="order.recip_id" placeholder="id" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">
            <option *ngFor="let item of recips" 
                   [value]="recip_id"
                   [selected]="recip_id === 'item.recip_id'">
                {{ item.name }}
                
                 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="order.name"  value="{{ item.recip_id }}" name="recipId"  > 
            </option>
          </select>
  <ng-container>

      <br><br><br>
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="createOrders()">Save</button>
```

And the success is that I got drop downlist based on "recip.name" but now I have to pass Id value of selected name to Orders. As for now I'm getting error:

```
error: "Internal Server Error"
```

​​`message: "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a];`

table which looks like this:

```html
Field,Type,Null,Key,Default,Extra
orders_id,bigint(20),NO,PRI,NULL,auto_increment
date,datetime(6),YES,,NULL,
recip_recip_id,bigint(20),NO,MUL,NULL,
```

Comment: This looks like a SQL query error to me have you checked backend logs to what the actual error is ? how are you firing a query from the front end directly without an API ?

Comment: I guess it's problem with what comes from component to Database (the Angular part). There is terrible mix of names and "id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you bind your `select` element isn't correct, you are over-complicating it.
I suggest you simply save the selected object in your component and use that object's id to create the new SQL entry.

Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5qs568) to give you an idea of what I mean

This is all assuming the problem comes from the Angular logic and not the SQL implementation.